# Gravatar always shows default image

Tags: gravatar

When I call the following code:

```
echo get_avatar(
    get_the_author_meta('user_email'), 
    '70', 
    get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/images/default.png"
);
```

It generates the following:

> ```
> [http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/f456a030d4086504d0796f0134139410?s=70&d=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.com%2Fscience-and-medical%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2FBlog%2Fimages%2Fdefault.png%3Fs%3D70&r=G][1]
> ```

It is adding to the end of the default URL:

```
%3Fs%3D70
```

This prevents it from working and always returns the default image. If you remove the extra data from the URL it works.

Comment: Quotes were needed around the parameter

Comment: Please add this as answer, then mark it as solution in 2 days. Thanks.

Comment: Will do, just at the moment the system will not let me

Comment: Sure, you can add an answer. What exactly does the system tell you?

Comment: "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You may self-answer in 2 hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead." - So guess just need to wait

Comment: Ah, ok. You need two upvotes on a question or one upvote or solution on one answer. Hope this pushes you in the direction, where you start to answer some questions! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out I needed to add quotes around the parameter.

```
echo get_avatar(get_the_author_meta('user_email'), '70', "'" . get_bloginfo('template_directory')."/images/default.png'");
```